# Matrix Multiplier Error - Switching Max to Sum

Tags: r, matrix, sum, max, matrix-multiplication

I have two dataframes one with information on animal found in one location (df1) and another with information on the characteristic of the animal (df2)

I am trying to use the matrix multiplier (%*%) and apply functions such as 'sum' and 'max' and obtain the information in each location.

For Eg:

```
df1:
 Location No. Dog Cat Cow Sheep
    1            0   2   2   1
    2            0   1   0   1
    3            0   0   0   1
    4            0   0   2   1

df2:
Name of Animal  BodySize   FavoriteScore
Dog             40         10
Cat             20         08
Cow             100        05
Sheep           60         07
```

My objective is to obtain information such as 
1. How many types of animals are there per location?
2. What is the largest animal found in each location? (where in it compares across all the animals and picks the largest bodysize and delivers it)
3. Which animal has the highest FavoriteScore in each location? (where in it compares across all the animals and picks the largest favoritescore and delivers it)

To obtain this I am using the following code:

```
Typemaker <- function (n) {
  o<-sum(n>0)
  return(o)
} 

apply(df1[,1:4] ,1, Typemaker)
df1$sumtype <- apply(df1[,2:5] ,1, Typemaker)

and 
Favoritemaker <- function (n) {
  o<- max(n %*% df2$FavoriteScore)
  return(o)
} 
apply(df1[,1:4] ,1, Favoritemaker)
df1$Favorite <-  apply(df1[,2:5] ,1, Favoritemaker)
or 
Bodysizemaker <- function (n) {
  o<- max(n %*% df2$BodySize)
  return(o)
} 
apply(df1[,1:4] ,1, Bodysizemaker).
df1$Bodysize <- apply(df1[,2:5] ,1, Bodysizemaker).
```

So that my answer would appear as:

```
 Location No. Dog Cat Cow Sheep Type Favorite Bodysize
    1            0   2   2   1     3    08       100
    2            0   1   0   1     2    08       20
    3            0   0   0   1     1    07       60
    4            0   0   2   1     2    07       100
```

However, the bodysize and favoritescores are being provided as a total of the row rather the largest value.

I am not sure of what exactly is the issue.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: What do you believe the `%*%` operator to do?

Comment: Please describe what you would like to do. Your question currently discusses your approach without describing explicitly what you intend to have making it an XY problem. It is specifically unclear what you intend to do with `%*%` and how that should rely on `max`.

Comment: @NelsonGon: Is the question reading better now?

Comment: @Roland: is the question reading better now?

Comment: @Roland: Why do you say so?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed is that when you called each function with `apply` you were using the first four columns, `df1[,1:4]` which includes the location number and excludes the Sheep data.  You should change this to `df1[,2:5]`.

I've never used the matrix multiplier, `%*%`, so I can't speak to the correct way to use it for this problem or even if it's a correct approach.  But since you have data frames the below is a very clunky way to use `dplyr` to get the result you wanted:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(`Location No.` = c(1:4),
                  Dog = rep(0,4),
                  Cat = c(2,1,0,0),
                  Cow = c(2,0,0,2),
                  Sheep = rep(1,4))

df2 <- data.frame(`Name of Animal` = c("Dog", "Cat", "Cow", "Sheep"),
                  BodySize = c(40, 20, 100, 60),
                  FavoriteScore = c(10, 8, 5, 7))

dfout <- df1 %>% 
           mutate(DogSize = ifelse(Dog > 0, df2$BodySize[df2$Name.of.Animal == "Dog"], 0),
                  CatSize = ifelse(Cat > 0, df2$BodySize[df2$Name.of.Animal == "Cat"], 0),
                  CowSize = ifelse(Cow > 0, df2$BodySize[df2$Name.of.Animal == "Cow"], 0),
                  SheepSize = ifelse(Sheep > 0, df2$BodySize[df2$Name.of.Animal == "Sheep"], 0)) %>%
           mutate(DogScore = ifelse(Dog > 0, df2$FavoriteScore[df2$Name.of.Animal == "Dog"], 0),
                  CatScore = ifelse(Cat > 0, df2$FavoriteScore[df2$Name.of.Animal == "Cat"], 0),
                  CowScore = ifelse(Cow > 0, df2$FavoriteScore[df2$Name.of.Animal == "Cow"], 0),
                  SheepScore = ifelse(Sheep > 0, df2$FavoriteScore[df2$Name.of.Animal == "Sheep"], 0)) %>% 
           rowwise() %>% 
           mutate(Bodysize = max(DogSize, CatSize, CowSize, SheepSize),
                  Favorite = max(DogScore, CatScore, CowScore, SheepScore)) %>% 
           select(Location.No., Dog, Cat, Cow, Sheep, Favorite, Bodysize)
```

There are definitely more efficient ways to do this, especially if your data set is larger, but this will get you to the table you showed at the end of your question:

```
Location.No. Dog Cat Cow Sheep Favorite Bodysize
1            0   2   2   1     8        100
2            0   1   0   1     8        60
3            0   0   0   1     7        60
4            0   0   2   1     7        100
```

**UPDATE**

OK so I was super curious for my own learning so the below is an updated code that uses gather and spread to make the process more versatile for a data set with more columns.  This should work with more columns provided the structure is similar to the sample data you showed.

```
df_long <- gather(df1, animal, count, Dog:Sheep, factor_key = TRUE)
```

This will take the first data frame in wide format and convert it to a long format for easier manipulation.  Just replace `Dog:Sheep` with the range of your animal columns.

```
df_modified <- df_long %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  # assign favorite score and body size by animal
  mutate(Favorite = df2$FavoriteScore[df2$Name.of.Animal == animal],
         Bodysize = df2$BodySize[df2$Name.of.Animal == animal]) %>% 
  # eliminate score and body size for animals without a count
  mutate(Favorite = case_when(count == 0 ~ 0,
                          TRUE ~ Favorite)) %>% 
  mutate(Bodysize = case_when(count == 0 ~ 0,
                          TRUE ~ Bodysize)) %>% 
  # use group_by and max() to get the max value for each location
  group_by(Location.No.) %>% 
  mutate(Favorite = max(Favorite),
         Bodysize = max(Bodysize))


# use spread to put the data frame back into the wide format
df_wide <- spread(df_modified, animal, count)

# use as.data.frame to get from tibble to dataframe
df_out <- as.data.frame(df_wide)
```

New output looks like this:

```
Location.No. Favorite Bodysize Dog Cat Cow Sheep
1            8        100      0   2   2   1
2            8        60       0   1   0   1
3            7        60       0   0   0   1
4            7        100      0   0   2   1
```

Comment: Thank you :) But my original data consists of two dataframes, one with 104 rows and the other with 50 types of animals, so I am a little afraid to do that because I might end up with errors. And yes! Thank you so much for pointing out the error, I will correct it

Comment: @KeerthiKrutha I updated the answer to try and be more versatile to a larger data set.  Hopefully this is useful for you.